# Array Difference for multi dimentional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have two array

```
$array1 = array
(
    array('A',0),
    array('B',0),
    array('C',0),
    array('D',0),
    array('E',0),
    array('F',0),
)

$array2 = array
(
    array('A',5),
    array('B',6),
    array('C',10),
    array('F',23),
)
```

$array2 will be changing sometimes A keys is there or its not there. It is applied for all keys.

I want to create a new array or replace the array values in $array1 to

```
$array1 = array
(
    array('A',5),
    array('B',6),
    array('C',10),
    array('D',0),
    array('E',0),
    array('F',23),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below

```
if(count($array1) > count($array2)){
    $tempArr1 = $array1;
    $tempArr2 = $array2;
}else{
    $tempArr1 = $array2;
    $tempArr2 = $array1;
}
$newArr = array();

foreach($tempArr1 as $values){
    $a = $values[0]; $n = $values[1];
    foreach($tempArr2 as $key=>$val){
        if($val[0] == $a){
            $n = ($val[1] > $n) ? $val[1] : $n;
            unset($tempArr2[$key]);
        }
    }
    $newArr[] = array($a, $n);
}
print_r($newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array1 = array (
  array('A',0),
  array('B',0),
  array('C',0),
  array('D',0),
  array('E',0),
  array('F',0),
);

$array2 = array (
  array('A',5),
  array('B',6),
  array('C',10),
  array('F',23),
);

foreach( $array2 as $itemKey2 => $itemVal2 ) {
  $found = false; 
  foreach( $array1 as $itemKey1 => $itemVal1   ) {
    if( $itemVal1[0] == $itemVal2[0] ) {
      $found = true;
      $array1[$itemKey1][1] = $itemVal2[1];
      break;
    }
  }
  if( !$found )
    $array1[] = $item2;
}

echo var_export( $array1, true );
```

In retrospect, this scenario seems needlessly complicated.  Unless something else truly requires this structure, if possible use something like:

```
$array1 = array (
  'A' => 0,
  'B' => 0,
  'C' => 0,
  'D' => 0,
  'E' => 0,
  'F' => 0
);

$array2 = array (
  'A' => 5,
  'B' => 6,
  'C' => 10,
  'F' => 23
);

foreach( $array2 as $key => $val ) {
    $array1[$key] = $val;
}
```